# 1980s horror movie with a monster in a swimming pool

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've a recollection of a film I watched as a kid (vastly under-aged).  It was more than likely 1980s in origin, or at the very latest very early 1990s. It was almost certainly horror.

A lot of the film was set around a big swimming pool, not a house pool, but a public pool.  The pool had a lot of steam/smoke over it.  I'm pretty sure there was some sort of monster in the pool, but it may have been able to move around as well, I'm not sure.

There was a scene that involved tampering with a CCTV camera.  (Possibly someone trying to get to the monster without it knowing?)  It was a very dark and atmospheric film, very low lighting, low budget etc.

Google searches have thrown up TerrorVision but I'm pretty sure this wasn't it as that was set in a house, and the pool was a small one.

Comment: Sounds familiar, but the film I remember has large rats (and one white rat) in the pool, attacking swimmers.

Answer (score 6):

Could this be **[Poltergeist 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poltergeist_III)**?

There's a swimming pool in the building. A group of teens sneaking in. They are concerned about being caught by the cctv.... It all seems to fit except my memory also has the group breaking in from the outside. More of a leisure centre.

Pool scene

[image]

[image]

[image]

A bit later on in the film the pool instantly freezes over and one of the teens bursts through the ice.

[image: pool scene]

I'm still not sure it's the film so I'll keep thinking.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding in some screenshots and removing the chatter at the start of the answer. An excellent find, even if it's not the right answer.

Comment: Monster wasn't in the pool, it was in a puddle; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pT9FGZ2efo